# Using a dynamic array formula in a dynamic array column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays, excel-365

Since we apparently can't use dynamic arrays in structured tables, I'm trying to use dynamic arrays in a dynamic table. Unfortunately, the main roadblock I've run into is looking up data on a different sheet which also uses columns created by dynamic arrays.

I have this, which works. However, this is a standard column, not dynamic, in which AJ4 and I4 become AJ5 and I5 in row 5, etc:

```
=IF(AJ4 = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4#, "not found", 0))
```

I'd like to have:

```
=IF(AJ4# = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4#, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4#, "not found", 0))
```

but so far I haven't found a variation that works as I want. I've mostly been working with variations of this:

```
=IF(AJ4 = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4:$D$1917, Listing!$T$4:$T$1917, "not found", 0))
```

What I'd REALLY like is some variation of this:

```
=IF(AJ4# = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4:M4#, Listing!$D$4:$E$4#, Listing!$T$4:$T$4#, "not found", 0))
```

although I can do extra comparisons to work around.

I have the 'IF(AJ4# = "", "",...)' in there to force it to be a dynamic array. I've also tried several other functions; I was using XLOOKUP here, thinking that as a new function it might have better support for what I'm trying to do.

The following all work, but Excel treats them as standard formulas, not dynamic array formulas:

```
=IF(INDEX($AJ$4#, ROW(A1)) = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4:$T$1917,
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$E$4#, Listing!$T$4:$T$1917, "n/a"), 0))
```

```
=IF(INDEX($AJ$4#, ROW(A1)) = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$U$4:$U$1917,
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$E$4#, Listing!$U$4:$U$1917, "n/a"), 0))
```

```
=IF(AJ4 = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4#,
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$E$4#, Listing!$T$4#, "n/a"), 0))
```

```
=IF(INDEX($AJ$4#, ROW(A1)) = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4#,
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$E$4#, Listing!$T$4#, "n/a"), 0))
```

```
=IF(INDEX($AJ$4#, ROW(A1)) = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$U$4:$U$1917,
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$E$4#, Listing!$U$4:$U$1917, "n/a"), 0))
```

T is a dynamic column, U is a standard column.

Comment: Can you replace `AJ4#` with `INDEX($AJ$4#,ROW(A1)) and try. I have not tried and not tested.

Comment: I tried:
=IF(AJ4# = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(INDEX($I$4#, ROW(A1)), Listing!$D$4#, 'Listing!$T$4#, "n/a", 0))
but got identical value in every row. Index() is the other issue I've been having trouble with.

Comment: No sir, not there, instead this way `=IF(INDEX($AJ$4#,ROW(A1)) = "", "",
@XLOOKUP(I4, Listing!$D$4#, Listing!$T$4#, "not found", 0))`

Comment: Sorry, @MayukhBhattacharya, doesn't work. I've updated the question to list what DOES work -- except they're standard, not dynamic.

Comment: Alright, then i have to test, can you post some dummy data with a worksheet link, if its okay with you. I can give a try